# Debug info out of iPhone X frame's bounds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

As you can see below in the simulator screen, the fps debug info gets cropped out.
I know it is merely a debug functionality and it will not be delivered to production but it just bugs me.

Is there a way to display the debug info correctly? Thank you.

Here is how the GameScene is initialised:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        let scene: SKScene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        view.presentScene(scene)

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: For whomever downvoted the question, I would appreciate to know how so, to not repeat the same mistake. Thank you.

Comment: You are going to have to take this up with apple,  But from what I am seeing, your view appears to be a bit wider than the iphone x, which is odd.  What is the view.bound.size that you are getting?  You may need to go into the storyboard and fix it to allow for the view to be confined to the screen borders (The default already does this last I used it)

Comment: maybe that is as wide, the only info you are missing is the "ps" in FPS

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `view` is not in a safe area. Use `self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame` to get the frame in which it's safe to show content and it won't be blocked.

Comment: Keep in mind that the OP may want to show the contents of the SKView outside of the safe area as well. The issue is only the position of the FPS and node counter.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that didn't do it.